# Visible Property in decompiler instr

Tags: c#, decompiler, ildasm

I need to know how can I find the Visible property of a MenuStrip in assembly.
I created a simple WinForms Project and I added a menuStrip. Then I changed the Visible property to true/false. 
I am decompiling with ildasm.exe but I cannot spot the difference that specifies if the menuStrip is visible or not, the instructions are identical.

Comment: Show us some code.

Comment: I already said that I created a new WinForms project and dragged a MenuStrip Control on the form. What code should I display?